# Program output with template and typedef classes

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public: 
      void K()
       {
          cout<<"1";
       };
};
class B{
public: typedef A T;
      void K()
      {
          cout<<"2";
      };
};
class C{
public:
      void K()
      {
          cout<<"3";
      };
};
class D{
    public:
    void K()
    {
        cout<<"4";
    };
};
template <class D=A> class E{
public: typedef D T;
    void K()
    {
       cout<<"5";
    };
};
template <> class E<A>{
public:typedef C T;
    void K()
    {
        cout<<"6";
    };
};
template <>class E<C>{
public:typedef B T;
     void K()
     {
       cout<<"7";
     };
};
template <class W, class V=E<W> >
class F{
typedef typename V::T R;
public:
     void K()
     {
         V().K();
         W().K();
         R().K();
    };
};
  int main(){
  E<>().K();
  F<A>().K();
  F<C>().K();
  return 0;
}
```

I cant ounderstand why the program output is 6 -- 612 -- 732. If someone could help me how this program works it would be awesome , even with the first line of main.If someone could tell me why the first cout is 6 step-by-step , that woudl be awesome.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: [Does that clarify a bit more?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a58abdf4e557a8ae)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be due to template ordering rules.  Let's examine things more closely.

```
int main(){
  E<>().K();  // Line 1.
  F<A>().K(); // Line 2.
  F<C>().K(); // Line 3.
  return 0;
}
```

---

## Line 1:

Here, we're trying to match template pattern `E<>`.  Our options are:

```
// Primary template.
template <class D=A> class E{
public: typedef D T;
    void K()
    {
       cout<<"5";
    };
};

// Specialisation for A.
template <> class E<A>{
public:typedef C T;
    void K()
    {
        cout<<"6";
    };
};

// Specialisation for C.
template <>class E<C>{
public:typedef B T;
     void K()
     {
       cout<<"7";
     };
};
```

The compiler examines the primary template, and sees that the default parameter is `A`; it therefore fills in the blank, resolving the template to `E<A>`.  This causes it to match one of the specialisations, so that specialisation is then chosen.

```
  E<>().K();  // Calls E<A>::K().
```

---

## Line 2.

As with line 1, since one of the parameters wasn't specified, the compiler fills in the blank, resolving the template to `F<A, E<A>>`.  Therefore, `W` is `A`, `V` is `E<A>`, and R is `E<A>::T`, or `C`.  This resolves to the following functions being called:

```
template <class W, class V=E<W> >
class F{
typedef typename V::T R;
public:
     void K()
     {
         V().K(); // Calls E<A>::K().
         W().K(); // Calls A::K().
         R().K(); // Calls C::K().
    };
};
```

---

## Line 3:

As with Line 2, the compiler fills in the blank, resolving to `F<C, E<C>>`.  Therefore, `W` is `C`, `V` is `E<C>`, and `R` is `E<C>::T`, or `B`.  This resolves to the following functions being called:

```
template <class W, class V=E<W> >
class F{
typedef typename V::T R;
public:
     void K()
     {
         V().K(); // Calls E<C>::K().
         W().K(); // Calls C::K().
         R().K(); // Calls B::K().
    };
};
```

---

And now that we've resolved the templates...

```
int main(){
  E<>().K();  // E<A>::K().
  F<A>().K(); // F<A, E<A>>::K() -> E<A>::K(), A::K(), C::K().
  F<C>().K(); // F<C, E<C>>::K() -> E<C>::K(), C::K(), B::K().
  return 0;
}
```

The output is therefore...

```
6613732
```

<sup>[Note: If your compiler gave you the output `6612732`, it wasn't supposed to.  Clang, GCC, and MSVC all agree that the proper output here is `6613732`.]</sup>

Comment: Yup, the correct output is really 6613732 , my bad . Thank you very much for your time and you helping me out !